# ASP.Net - Safari alert - Are you sure you want to leave this page?

Tags: asp.net, safari

Asp.Net application 1 - webpage contains a hyperlink, say ShowReport
ASP.Net application 2 - webpage Download.aspx

In app 1, When ShowReport link is clicked, I open the page Download.aspx(hosted in a separate web-site) to show the save/download dialog box to user:

ShowReport.href = [http://localhost:19515/Download.aspx]

In app2 - Download.aspx, I have something like:

```
            Response.ClearHeaders();  
            Response.ClearContent();  
            Response.Clear();  
            Response.ContentType = contentType.GetFriendlyName();  
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", file.Name));  
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());  
            Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
```

But while runnning app in Safari, when ShowReport link is clicked, I get an alert saying
'Are you sure you want to leave this page? You have unsaved changes. Click OK to leave or Cancel to stay'

Can anyone please guide me how can I get rid of this alert.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have `onbeforeunload` event handler somewhere there that returns a part of this message. Get rid of this first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is there any other way out, I do have onbeforehand in .js file included in the web page. But the issue is I have recently jumped in this huge project and the team members who worked on this project are no more around to query :-( Is there any way out you can think of? (don't want to break code)

Comment: @iniki ok. try to unbind the `onbeforeunload` from `window` object before needed action (click on link). With JQuery (if available) you can do it so: `$(window).unbind("onbeforeunload")`